# Can you specify webassembly extensions in deno deploy instances?

Tags: v8, webassembly, deno-deploy

Is there a way to configure a v8 isolate in deno deploy to enable certain webassembly extensions, that v8 doesn't yet enable by default? Or more generally, request any other optional v8 features that on the desktop need `--v8-flags`?

Comment: I don't know about Deno, but do note that most Wasm features that aren't yet enabled by default in V8 also aren't ready for production use yet.